# JMS listener for mutiply types od message?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I need to receive messages from queue in JSON format. So I implemented serializable/deserializable + JMS receiver for method with arguments of my POJO class (simple JSON)
But when I want to receive message not in JSON's format(for example String) my program of course crashed.
Maybe I must create two JMS listeners? But then  destination of second listener must be another queue channel?

P.S using IBM MQ

```
//MyMessage is class with my POJO  

@Component
public class MyMessageListener {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter converter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter() {

            @Override
            public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
                TextMessage message = (TextMessage) super.toMessage(object, session);
                System.out.println("outgoing JSON: " + message.getText());
                return message;
            }

            @Override
            public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("incoming JSON: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
                    } catch (JMSException e) { 
                        throw new MessageConversionException("Failed to convert JSON message content", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("This receiver only processes text messages!");
                }
                return super.fromMessage(message);
            }
        };

        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${input.queue}")
    public static void listener(MyMessage myMessage) throws JMSException {
        System.out.println("msg: " + myMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely it is possible to check whether the message you are about to process is JSON or plain string?

Comment: Depends on which JSON parser library you are using, but it should be throwing something like a ParseException when the data is not valid JSON. You should catch the ParseException when parsing

Comment: Its working after I deleted methods: toMessage and fromMessage(but converter stay) and now listener can receive all types of message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working after I deleted methods: toMessage and fromMessage(but converter stay) and now listener can receive all types of message.